# How can I save a PHP array to a PHP file with the right lines and spaces?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array, and I want save it to a PHP file, like `myfile.php`, but I want have the right spaces between one array to other. I need my file to look exactly like this array:

```
$array = [
    "one" => [
        "key1" => "value1",
        "key2" => "value2",
        "key3" => [
            "key1" => "value3",
            "key2" => "value4",
            "key3" => [
                "value5",
                "value6",
                "value7",
                "value8",
                "value9"
            ],
            "key4" => "value10",
            "key5" => "value11"
        ],
        "key4" => "value12",
        "key5" => "value13"
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to make it *exactly* like that, but you're probably looking for var_export..

```
<?php
$arr=["one" => [
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2",
    "key3" => [
        "key1" => "value3",
        "key2" => "value4",
        "key3" => [
            "key1" => "value5",
            "key2" => "value6",
            "key3" => "value7",
            "key4" => "value8",
            "key5" => "value9"
        ],
        "key4" => "value10",
        "key5" => "value11"
    ],
    "key4" => "value12",
    "key5" => "value13"

]];

file_put_contents('myfile.php', var_export($arr, true));
```

Comment: Yes its work but, i want make " [ " and not " array() " with var export dont close the array with " ; " i want a function to do that to allows me add and other options

Comment: in value5 makes me a  [0 => value5, 1 => value6]  this is not correct

Comment: @BrostaTools your data is not correct... i can't imagine var_export doing that mistake.  anyway, you can parse your code with var_export and token_get_all() and re-create your php code using [ ] instead of array(), but its gonna be much more complex than just using var_export..

Comment: Use json_encode not var_export, and make it a json file the u can use json_decode to use that array again.

Comment: Yes but i dont want use json i need make a function to make the arrays ready to save in php file, and i can not with that way. I need a code to make the array exactly with the example. And my code is correct, it is only an array, why is not correct? where is problem in only one array?

Comment: Ok now it is saved but is wrong in the file. I have make a better code but i need help to make spaces

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have updated! This is the perfect way.

```
function escapeString($str) {
    $escape = array(
        "\r" => '\r',
        "\n" => '\n',
        "\t" => '\t',
        "'" => "\\'",
        '"' => '\"',
        '\\' => '\\\\'
    );
    return strtr($str, $escape);
}


function arrayToString($array, $space=2, $level=0) {
    $var = "";
    $SLINE = "\t";
    $DLINE = "\n";
    if (is_array($array)) {
        $length = sizeof($array);
        $last = 0;
        foreach($array as $key => $x) {
            $newKey = '"' . $key . '"';
            if (is_array($x)) {
                $level++;
                $s = "";
                $ss = "";
                for ($j=0; $j < $level; $j++) {
                    if ($j>0)
                        $s.=$SLINE;
                        $ss.=$SLINE;
                    }
                if ($length>1 && $last!=$length - 1)
                    $coma = ',' . $DLINE;
                else
                    $coma = $DLINE;
                $var.=$s . "$newKey => [".$DLINE;
                $var.=arrayToString($x, $space, $level);
                $var.=$s . "]$coma";
                $level--;
            }
            else {
                $s = "";
                $ss = "";
                for ($j=0; $j < $level; $j++) {
                    if ($j > 0)
                        $s.=$SLINE;
                        $ss.=$SLINE;
                    }

                switch(gettype($x)) {

                    case 'boolean':
                        $value = $x ? 'true' : 'false';
                        break;

                    case 'integer':
                    case 'double':
                        $value = $x;
                        break;

                    case 'string':
                        $value = '"'.escapeString($x).'"';
                        break;

                    case 'NULL':
                        $value = 'null';
                        break;
                }
                if ($length>1 && $last!=$length - 1)
                    $coma = ',' . $DLINE;
                else
                    $coma = $DLINE;
                if (is_numeric($key))
                    $newKey = "";
                else
                    $newKey.=" => ";
                $var.=$ss . "$newKey$value$coma";
            }
            $last++;
        }
        return $var;
    }
}

$array = [
    "one" => [
        "key1" => "value1",
        "key2" => "value2",
        "key3" => [
            "key1" => "value3",
            "key2" => "value4",
            "key3" => [
                "value5",
                "value6",
                "key1" => [
                    "key1" => "value3",
                    "key2" => "value4",
                    "key3" => [
                        "value5",
                        "value6",
                        "value7",
                        "value8",
                        "value9"
                    ],
                    "key4" => "value10",
                    "key5" => "value11"
                ],
                "value8",
                "value9"
            ],
            "key4" => "value10",
            "key5" => "value11"
        ],
        "key4" => "value12",
        "key5" => "value13"
    ]
];

$DLINE = "\n";
$content = '<?php'.$DLINE.$DLINE;
$content .= arrayToString($array, $space=2);
$content .= $DLINE.'?>';

// refresh page and see your file
file_put_contents('yourFileName.php', $content);
```